# How can I declare hex vars in c#

Tags: c#, .net, hex

how can I declare 2 bytes hex in c# and compare in a "if" like this java code:

```
public static final int MSG_GENERAL_RESPONSE = 0x8001;

int type = buf.readUnsignedShort();

if (type == MSG_TERMINAL_REGISTER) {
}
```

c# 2 bytes is not possible in c#? I tried and havent found a way. How can I translate this code to c#?

Comment: Its the same in C#. C# use BitConverter class. There you can convert it using BitConverter.ToUInt16 to convert byte array to unsigned short, or use BitConverter.GetBytes to convert it from unsigned short to byte array

Comment: If you remove the `final` keyword, that's valid C# code.  In C# the `short` data type is 2 bytes.  I don't understand what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

It would be OK to use `int` in your case (that is a signed 32-bit integer type), but it looks like `ushort` (unsigned 16-bit) is more precise here:

```
public const ushort MSG_GENERAL_RESPONSE = 0x8001;

// ...

ushort type = buf.readUnsignedShort();

if (type == MSG_TERMINAL_REGISTER) {
}
```

Note that if you want to give a *negative* literal in hexadecimal (with the convention that when the leading digit is from `8` through `F`, then it is two's complement), you need the following clumsy notation:

```
// negative:
public const short MSG_GENERAL_RESPONSE = unchecked((short)0x8001);
```

You cannot use `final` in C#. For a class member, you can use `static readonly` or `const` (the latter is implicitly static). For a local variable you can use `const`.